# Bulk Insert into SQL Server from text file adding a uniqueidentifier, or skipping a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I need to take rows from a text file and insert into a table. The rows of the file are similar to the following:

```
string1
string2
string3
string4
...
```

My table has 2 columns:

```
uniqueidentifier, stringValue
```

I would like to do a bulk insert into the table grabbing each row from the text file and adding a new `uniqueidentifier` to each one (ideally a GUID, but an integer counter would be fine).

Anyone have a tip on how to do this bulk upload? So far my SQL is:

```
BULK
INSERT tableNameToInsertInto
FROM 'C:\importList.txt'
WITH
(
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Comment: define your uniquedentifier column as having a default of NEWID()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one -

**Values:**

```
C:\importList.txt ->
string1
string2
string3
string4
```

**Format file:**

```
C:\importList.fmt ->
11.0
1
1     SQLCHAR     0     100     "\r\n"     1     text     ""
```

**Query:**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.testBulk 
(
      RowUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID()
    , Value VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.testBulk (Value)
SELECT c.[text]
FROM OPENROWSET(
    BULK N'C:\importList.txt', 
    FORMATFILE = 'C:\importList.fmt'
) c
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I copied and pasted your suggestion for the format file into a notepad file, then renamed the file from a .txt to a .fmt. Next, I ran the create and the create and the insert. Pretty straight forward! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Although this is a very old question, may I ask why do we need a format file? I was too having the same issue, and using your format file solved it for me.
Thanks in advance @Devart :)